# How to determine company of individual account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I need to know, if I publish the app from my individual developer account what name is it going to appear on store.

I dont remember the company name I submitted the first time.

[image]

Comment: Above screenshot, indicates that. Company name will be shown when you are publishing app from the company account.

Comment: Yes, above screenshot is taken from Apple's documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH11-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are publishing app with your individual developer account, then it will be published and shown with your "First Name Last Name".

Moreover, The company name will not be shown, but copyright, you mention at the time of creating App in iTunesConnect Account will be shown on the app store. Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back this up?

Comment: @SaqibSaud I am telling from the reference of the app which I published on appstore from my individual developer account.